# Format column-based text file into tree structure using bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, text-formatting

Is there a Unix/Linux command that can turn this:

```
AMERICA USA NEW_YORK    AB-100
AMERICA USA NEW_YORK    VF-200
AMERICA USA NEW_YORK    XY-243
AMERICA USA LOS_ANGELES UH-198
AMERICA CANADA  TORONTO UT-876
AMERICA CANADA  TORONTO UT-877
AMERICA CANADA  VANCOUVER   UT-871
AMERICA CANADA  VANCOUVER   UT-872
AMERICA CANADA  VANCOUVER   UT-873
AMERICA MEXICO  MEXICO  OU-098
AMERICA MEXICO  MONTERREY   OU-099
AMERICA MEXICO  MONTERREY   OU-100
EUROPE  FRANCE  PARIS   IV-122
EUROPE  FRANCE  PARIS   AV-112
EUROPE  FRANCE  PARIS   IF-111
EUROPE  FRANCE  PARIS   XX-190
EUROPE  FRANCE  TOULOUSE    TL-654
```

Into this:

```
AMERICA
    USA
        NEW_YORK
            AB-100
            VF-200
            XY-243
        LOS_ANGELES
            UH-198
    CANADA  
        TORONTO 
            UT-876
            UT-877
        VANCOUVER
            UT-871
            UT-872
            UT-873
    MEXICO  
        MEXICO  
            OU-098
        MONTERREY
            OU-099
            OU-100
EUROPE
    FRANCE
        PARIS
            IV-122
            AV-112
            IF-111
            XX-190
        TOULOUSE
            TL-654
```

Comment: Why using bash? Can we use different tools? Bash can do this but it will be needlessly complex.

Comment: Given the spacing in your data I suppose the input fields are TAB separated?

Comment: @yes, it's TAB separated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `awk`, you could do:

```
$ awk '{
        a[$1][$2][$3] ? 
            a[$1][$2][$3]=a[$1][$2][$3]"\n\t\t\t"$4 :
            a[$1][$2][$3]="\t\t\t"$4 ;
      }
      END{
        for(cont in a){
            printf "%s\n", cont;
            for(count in a[cont]){
                printf "\t%s\n", count;
                for(city in a[cont][count]){
                    print "\t\t"city"\n"a[cont][count][city]
      }}}}' file
EUROPE
    FRANCE
        TOULOUSE
            TL-654
        PARIS
            IV-122
            AV-112
            IF-111
            XX-190
AMERICA
    USA
        NEW_YORK
            AB-100
            VF-200
            XY-243
        LOS_ANGELES
            UH-198
    CANADA
        VANCOUVER
            UT-871
            UT-872
            UT-873
        TORONTO
            UT-876
            UT-877
    MEXICO
        MEXICO
            OU-098
        MONTERREY
            OU-099
            OU-100
```

In Perl:

```
perl -lane 'push @{$k{$F[0]}{$F[1]}{$F[2]}},"\t\t\t".$F[3];
            END{
                for $cont (keys(%k)){
                    print "$cont";
                    for $coun (keys(%{$k{$cont}})){
                        print "\t$coun";
                        for $city (keys(%{$k{$cont}{$coun}})){
                            print "\t\t$city\n", 
                              join "\n",@{$k{$cont}{$coun}{$city}}
             }}}}' file
EUROPE
    FRANCE
        PARIS
            XX-190
            XX-190
        TOULOUSE

            TL-654
AMERICA
    USA
        NEW_YORK
            XY-243
            XY-243
        LOS_ANGELES

            UH-198
    MEXICO
        MONTERREY
            OU-100
            OU-100
        MEXICO

            OU-098
    CANADA
        VANCOUVER
            UT-873
            UT-873
        TORONTO
            UT-877
            UT-877
```

Comment: `awk: line 2: syntax error at or near [` ...in Ubuntu

Comment: @user1598390 that's odd. Did you copy/paste directly into your shell or did you copy it manually?

Comment: @user1598390 see updated answer. There were some bugs in the awk code (though they wouldn't have given that error) and I also added  Perl solution.

Comment: The perl version runs but prints 2 items at most at the end of a branch, for example new york has three items but it only prints two and those two are the last one repeated.

Comment: @user1598390 sorry again, another bug. The new version should work. I'm still curious about the awk though. I just tested again and it works fine.

Comment: @terdon; Nice! - Note, though, that multi-dimentional arrays are non-standard. Standard `awk`s only support the syntax `a[$1,$2,$3]` which does not allow implementing the program logic in that nice way. Newer versions of GNU `awk` (for example) specifically do support multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: @Janis thanks for the heads up. Would that explain the error reported by the OP in the first comment? I'd be surprised if Ubuntu didn't have a recent gawk.

Comment: @terdon; Yes, that explains the OP's observation. - The `/usr/bin/awk` on my Ubuntu is still version 3.1.8, and I think you'd need a 4.x version for multi-dimensional array support.

Answer (score 8):

For your example:

```
dir=$(mktemp -d)
sed 's|\t|/|g' file | while read -r line; do mkdir -p "$dir/$line"; done
(cd "$dir"; tree)
rm -r "$dir"
```

Output:

```
.
├── AMERICA
│   ├── CANADA
│   │   ├── TORONTO
│   │   │   ├── UT-876
│   │   │   └── UT-877
│   │   └── VANCOUVER
│   │       ├── UT-871
│   │       ├── UT-872
│   │       └── UT-873
│   ├── MEXICO
│   │   ├── MEXICO
│   │   │   └── OU-098
│   │   └── MONTERREY
│   │       ├── OU-099
│   │       └── OU-100
│   └── USA
│       ├── LOS_ANGELES
│       │   └── UH-198
│       └── NEW_YORK
│           ├── AB-100
│           ├── VF-200
│           └── XY-243
└── EUROPE
    └── FRANCE
        ├── PARIS
        │   ├── AV-112
        │   ├── IF-111
        │   ├── IV-122
        │   └── XX-190
        └── TOULOUSE
            └── TL-654
```

Comment: Now that's _sneaky_, well done! I suggest using `dir=$(mktemp -d);sed 's| \+|/|g' file | while read -r line; do mkdir -p "$dir/$line"; done; tree "$dir" | sed 's/[│└─├]\+/ /g'; rm -r "$dir"` to i) avoid the needless cds and ii) remove the indentation characters.

Comment: @Cyrus; Interesting idea! -Though I'd not create a lot of directories where all we need is just text-processing. - Note also that the single `cd` in your code is wrong; it works only if you happen to have been in your `HOME` directory when starting the code sequence. Either use `cd -` or perform `cd "$dir"; tree` in a subshell `(cd "$dir"; tree)` and remove the final `cd`.

Comment: @Janis: I've updated my answer with your hint to use a subshell.

Answer (score 5):

An `awk` script that works with standard `awk`s, keeps the lines in its original order, and works with an arbitrary number of columns in the data:

```
awk -F $'\t' '
  function indent (n, i) { for (i=1; i<=n; i++) printf "\t" }

  { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
        if ($i != o[i]) {
            printf "%s%s\n", indent(i-1), $i
            o[i] = $i
        }
  }
'
```

The same program logic can be implemented in shell. For `bash`:

```
indent () { ind=$( printf "%*s" "$1" '' ) ; printf "${ind// /$'\t'}" ;}

while IFS=$'\t' read -a f
do
    for ((i=0; i<${#f}; i++))
    do
        if [[ "${f[i]}" != "${o[i]}" ]]
        then
            printf "%s%s\n" "$( indent "$i" )" "${f[i]}"
            o[i]=${f[i]}
        fi
    done
done
```

Note: For `ksh` you have to adjust `read -a` by `read -A`.